# python3におけるKeyErrorについて

Tags: python, python3

pythonを勉強し始めた者です。
「N個の座標(x,y)に対し、それぞれの原点からの距離を求め、距離が小さいものから順に5つ足したものを出力する」
という問題があったとします。入力は以下の通りです。
一行目がN、以下が各x y座標とします。

> 7
>   1 2
>   3 4
>   6 5
>   4 2
>   8 9
>   3 5
>   3 2

それに対し、自分は以下のように作成しました。

```
import math
L = {}
XN = {}
YN = {}

value = 0
count = 0

N = int(input())
for i in range(N):
    XN[i], YN[i] = map(int, input().split())
    L[i] = math.sqrt(XN[i]**2+YN[i]**2)

while(count < 5):
    min = 999
    for i in range(N):
        if(min>L[i]):
            min = L[i]
            num = i
    value = value + min
    count = count + 1
    del L[i]
print(value)
```

すると,while内のif(min>L[i])にて
KeyErrorが発生してしまいました。
dic型は同一関数内でも別ループ内では使用できないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> dic型は同一関数内でも別ループ内では使用できないのでしょうか？

参照は可能です。

ただこの問題は単純に範囲エラーのようです。

```
del L[i]
```

にて配列をdelしているにもかかわらず
ループ回数は

```
 for i in range(N):
```

とNで固定となっております。
`len(L)`等にしてみてはいかがでしょうか

Comment: 恥ずかしながら気づきませんでした。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 問題が解決したらば、チェック✓マークアイコンをクリックして、質問の解決をお願いいたします。